# Get Timeline Button Disabled?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-timeline

I just made a new Facebook account, and I want to add timeline. But, apparently Facebook keeps the "[Get Timeline](http://www.facebook.com/about/timeline)" button [hidden from new users](http://filesmelt.com/dl/Screen_Shot_2012-04-03_at_11.14_.13_PM_.png).

So how could I get around this? Javascript through the address bar or maybe just a url?

```
<form rel="async" ajaxify="/ajax/timeline/activate.php?action=activate&amp;ref=marketing_page" class="buttonForm" action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return Event.__inlineSubmit(this,event)">
    <input type="hidden" name="lsd" value="AVoDDmtm" autocomplete="off">
    <label class="TimelineMarketingUpgradeButton uiButton uiButtonSpecial uiButtonLarge" for="ut0eri_8">
        <input value="Get Timeline" type="submit" id="ut0eri_8">
    </label>
</form>
```

Comment: You can get help from Facebook for user / account / site problems at https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=220217228006012 - this is not the correct forum for those questions (see http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq#questions  for more information)

Answer (score 0):

You can activate Timeline from this URL: http://www.facebook.com/about/timeline

Even if the button is hidden, accessing the page using the above URL still works.

Comment: Worked for me on several occasions in the past. Facebook might have disabled the functionality.